# How to write this sql query using doctrine query builder?

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm

How could I write this sql query on symfony query builder syntax?

Analysis, Region, Nature and Garden are Entities

```
SELECT * FROM `analysis`
    INNER JOIN sample ON sample.id = analysis.sample_id
    INNER JOIN region ON sample.region_id = region.id
    INNER JOIN nature ON sample.nature_id = nature.id
    INNER JOIN garden ON sample.garden_id = garden.id
    WHERE sample.stateProduct = 'Origin'
    AND analysis.status = '0'
    AND region.name = 'Jangsu'
    AND garden.name = 'North Tukvar'
    AND nature.name = 'Thé Vert'
    AND sample.sampleBio = '1'
    AND sample.supplierCountry = 'Inde'
```

I tried this way but, I don't have error msg, but it's not same result as sql query.

```
public function countAnalysisByCriteria($stateProduct, $status, Nature $nature, Region $region, Garden $garden, $supplierName, $bio, $country, $startDate, $endDate){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('analysis')
            ->addSelect('count(analysis) as result')
            ->innerJoin('analysis.sample', 'sample', 'WITH', 'analysis.sample = sample')
            ->innerJoin('sample.nature', 'nature', 'WITH', 'sample.nature = :nature')
            ->innerJoin('sample.region', 'region', 'WITH', 'sample.region = :region')
            ->innerJoin('sample.garden', 'garden', 'WITH', 'sample.garden = :garden')

            ->groupBy('result');

               ->andWhere('sample.stateProduct = :stateProduct');
               ->setParameter('stateProduct', $stateProduct);
               ->andWhere('sample.nature = :nature');
               ->setParameter('nature', $nature);
               ->andWhere('sample.region = :region');
               ->setParameter('region', $region);
               ->andWhere('sample.garden = :garden');
               ->setParameter('garden', $garden);
               ->andWhere('sample.dateReception BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate');
                $qb->setParameter('startDate', $startDate);
                $qb->setParameter('endDate', $endDate);
            }

        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet is completely wrong, try the following:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

public function countAnalysisByCriteria(
    $stateProduct,
    $status,
    Nature $nature,
    Region $region,
    Garden $garden,
    $supplierName,
    $bio,
    $country,
    $startDate,
    $endDate
) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();

    return $qb->select('count(analysis) as result')
        ->innerJoin('analysis.sample', 'sample', Join::WITH, 'analysis.sample = sample.id')
        ->innerJoin('sample.nature', 'nature', Join::WITH, 'sample.nature = nature.id')
        ->innerJoin('sample.region', 'region', Join::WITH, 'sample.region = region.id')
        ->innerJoin('sample.garden', 'garden', Join::WITH, 'sample.garden = garden.id')
        ->groupBy('result')
        ->andWhere('sample.stateProduct =:stateProduct')
        ->setParameter('stateProduct', $stateProduct)
        ->andWhere('sample.nature =:nature')
        ->setParameter('nature', $nature)
        ->andWhere('sample.region =:region')
        ->setParameter('region', $region)
        ->andWhere('sample.garden =:garden')
        ->setParameter('garden', $garden)
        ->andWhere('sample.dateReception BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate')
        ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
        ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
}
```

- **DO NOT** add spaces on assignments `= :` (wrong), `=:` (right)
- Check your code properly, notice how I have removed some colon `;` at some pieces because does not make sense have them there.

Comment: Thanks for these advices ReynierPM, this is working ! my mistake on the innerjoin : ":nature" instead of "nature.id"